# Rails - Devise/Omniauth - No Method Error Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to integrate facebook authentication with devise.

I used this tutorial (http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin) and got it to work locally, but I keep getting an error when I push to heroku.  I have already changed the links in the Facebook dev/apps part to the actual domain.

I have the following code in `production.rb`.  For "app_domain" part, I've tried to put in all types of app domain variations (the domain, domain.com, heroku app name, etc.) but I have no idea what should go there.

I'm a new coder, so would appreciate any help!

```
# Email for omniauth facebook auth
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => config.app_domain }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
port: '587',
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: 'someuser',
password: 'somepass',
authentication => :plain,
domain => 'somedomain.com'
}
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `app_domain' for
>
> ```
>    /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in
> ```
>
> `method_missing'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/config/environments/production.rb:100:in`
>   block in '
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in
>   `instance_eval'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in`
>   configure'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/config/environments/production.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in
>   `each'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in`
>   block in '
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `instance_exec'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   run'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
>   `block in run_initializers'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in`
>   each'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
>   `tsort_each_child'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   run_initializers'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in
>   `initialize!'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/config/environment.rb:5:in`
>   '
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`block in require'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in
>   `require_environment!'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in`
>   block in run_tasks_blocks'
>          /tmp/build_9557c4b1-3f72-41e9-bc67-afe937d8b044/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:55:in
>   `block (2 levels) in define'
>          Tasks: TOP => environment
>          (See full trace by running task with --trace)  !  !     Precompiling assets failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message, "undefined method `app_domain'" stems from this line:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => config.app_domain }
```

Just as it says, you haven't assigned an `app_domain` property on your `config` option. Action Mailer is the part of Rails that sends emails, and it uses this setting to generate links back to your application.

You could just add `config.app_domain = "myapp.herokuapp.com"` to the top of your `config/environments/production.rb` file. But this is hard-coded; an alternative is to use an environment variable instead.

[Heroku uses their `config` command for this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars); run `heroku config:set APP_DOMAIN=myapp.herokuapp.com` in the terminal to set it, and then use `ENV['APP_DOMAIN']` in your Ruby app to access it. So your config line would look like this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['APP_DOMAIN'] }
```

Finally, you have a `domain` setting as part of the `smtp_settings` block at the bottom. You might want to make that use your new setting too.

Comment: Thanks Alex!  Got rid of those errors with your changes and some I found in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272716/local-variable-or-method-config-for-mainobject-nameerror